# Action Script 3: Show Graphic on Hover?

Tags: actionscript-3, hover, visibility

Basicly I have a photo gallery which has graphic above the photos with text saying what the image is of. I am not sure on how to set the graphic to visible = false at the start of the flash movie? Also how would I achieve it so it only shows the graphic when the user has its mouse hovered over the certain images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you basically need to add two events to your object with a photo: MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT.  When user move mouse pointer on your photo, you will have a MOUSE_OVER event, so you will make the photo description visible.

`myHint.visible = true;`

And when mouse leave your photo you will have MOUSE_OUT event, where you can hide your hint `myHint.visible = false;`.

I recommend to create an object which has a photo and a hind as a children. So every photo will have it's own description object, and you could easily get them something like `myPhotoObject.myDescriptionHint`.

I also recommend you to read about [event handling](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/event_handling_as3.html) in the as3. This will answer most of your additional questions.

**UPDATE**

After comment from alxx, i found [this helpful article](http://www.zedia.net/2008/difference-between-mouseeventroll_over-and-mouseeventmouse_over-in-as3/) about difference between MOUSE_OVER and ROLL_OVER events

Comment: Correction: MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT. There is no need to react on MOUSE_OVER, which is called on every mouse movement over the object.

Comment: Actually, that's not the precise difference between ROLL_OVER and MOUSE_OVER. The difference is that ROLL_OVER is dispatched by the DisplayObject when you roll over it, whereas MOUSE_OVER is dispatched everytime you roll over it or any of its display children. You would normally use MOUSE_OVER/OUT when trying to differentiate between rolling over different children in a container. Confusing things further are the mouseChildren and mouseEnabled properties. Check out this blog post: http://www.zedia.net/2008/difference-between-mouseeventroll_over-and-mouseeventmouse_over-in-as3/

Comment: @Adan Smith, actually you pointed to the articles, that already was mentioned in my answer)